# How to use et.al (special case)?

Tags: reference

I'm writing about a javascript library. and i have the following example:

*"The founder of this JavaScript library, Jason M. Saragih, wrote an article [1] with et. al, reviewing considerations on how to accelerate their approach."*

I can see that this doesn't look right. How to best use the et.al in this case?

**Notes:**

library founder = 1 (Jason M. Saragih).

Article authors = 3 (Jason M. Saragih), (Simon Lucey), (Jeffrey F. Cohn)

Comment: Why do you not want to say "wrote an article with "Simon Lucey and Jeffrey F. Cohn?"

Comment: It’s written _et al._, not _et. al_. It stands for _et alii_ ‘and others’, and as you can see, it’s _alii_ (or _aliae_ for groups of women, _alia_ for groups of inanimate entities) which is abbreviated and thus requires the stop, not _et_, which is a complete word. And as @TaliesinMerlin writes, there is absolutely no reason here to use _et al._ – I’d go so far as to say that it would be quite bizarre to do so. _Et al._ is only used in bibliographic references, and this is not a bibliographic reference, but a full sentence.

Comment: "... Saragih, wrote, with two other authors, an article reviewing ..."

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to use *et al.* in that sentence, but if you really want to, you'd need to write something like:

"Jason M. Saragih, the founder of this JavaScript library, et al. wrote an article reviewing considerations on how to accelerate their approach."

*Et al.* means *and others*.  You cannot "write an article with *and others*."

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

(New revision by virtue of an excellent comment)

*"Jason M. Saragih, the founder of this JavaScript library, wrote, with others, an article reviewing considerations on how to accelerate their approach."*

Comment: Your compromise isn’t really a compromise – it’s just stripping the other two authors of their authorship. It’s also stripping Saragih of some of his foundership: as clarified in the question, he is the only founder of the library, but one of three authors of the article.

Comment: I repent of my original response. I conflated one of the original responses with the original question and had a context error in my answer. I agree completely with the reply and have offered a proposed structure.

Comment: Sounds like Morse code, but thank you friend